# Indesign index with tab right aligned

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create an index that uses right aligned numbers with leading dots. I've got a paragraph style that has the right aligned tab setup with the dots leading. What i don't know how to do is have the generated index use the tab character between the entry and the number. I can manually add the tab, and the paragraph style works perfectly but i'm not going to manually edit that index of 800 entries :) Where do i specify that i want a tab instead of spaces after the entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the index, press *More Options* and the following dialogue appears:

[image]

Empty the field called *Following Topic*, click the arrow next to it and choose *Tab Character*.

Answer (score 0):

Insert ^y in Following Topic :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114980)